# json remove element by value

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I have a json object :

```
myJson = [
{"id":"001", "name":"AAA"},
{"id":"002", "name":"BBB"},
{"id":"003", "name":"CCC"},
{"id":"004", "name":"DDD"}
]
```

How I can remove an element by value of id?

thank for your helps

Comment: [You don't have a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), you have an object. More specifically, you have an array of objects. The answer that silly posted is the simplest solution to removing an item, or you can use a standard loop to go through the array until you find the matching item and then use `.splice()` to remove it.

Comment: right. But I parsed this object to JSON

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can filter your array... as example: you want to remove every object with the id "003" use this:

```
myJson = myJson.filter(function(jsonObject) {
    return jsonObject.id != "003";
});
```

Comment: @Blacksonic yes, but the question does not refer to a browser

Comment: I suspect the OP would need `myJson = myJson.filter(...`

Comment: You're welcome. +1, by the way. @Blacksonic - Regarding compatibility of `.filter()` and other methods that IE didn't support until version 9, I decided recently not to bother mentioning that issue in my answers unless the question clearly mentions an older browser. I figure if I introduce somebody to a standard JS function they've never used it's up to them to look it up in [a good JS reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) - surely that's just good practice on their part? And said reference will tell them how to shim if needed.

Comment: i think its good to mention also pitfalls of it, btw good answer to the question, just wanted to add more information on it