# How to remove JSON object based on specific keyword

Tags: javascript, json

am trying to build an API for that am creating a JSON data to collect that am using web scraping

in the JSON file am also getting some bad objects for example

**JSON data** I get

```
[
   {
      "order":"1588668201-56",
      "pagenation":"",
      "pagenation-href":"",
      "courseid":"Redeem Offer",
      "courseid-href":"https://www.valid.comxyz"
   },
   {
      "order":"1588668201-57",      
      "pagenation":"",
      "pagenation-href":"",
      "courseid":"[Free] ClickHouse crash course. Conquer big data with ease",
      "courseid-href":"https://remove.com/xyz"
   },
   {
      "order":"1588668201-58",      
      "pagenation":"",
      "pagenation-href":"",
      "courseid":"Redeem Offer",
      "courseid-href":"https://www.valid.com/xyz"
   }
]
```

but the output which I want

```
[
   {
      "order":"1588668201-56",
      "pagenation":"",
      "pagenation-href":"",
      "courseid":"Redeem Offer",
      "courseid-href":"https://www.valid.comxyz"
   },
   {
      "order":"1588668201-58",      
      "pagenation":"",
      "pagenation-href":"",
      "courseid":"Redeem Offer",
      "courseid-href":"https://www.valid.com/xyz"
   }
]
```

if inside the JSON object key `courseid-href` starts with  `https://www.invalid.com` it should remove that complete object

I have tried 
**UPDATED**

```
    test =[
    {
       "order":"1588668201-56",
       "pagenation":"",
       "pagenation-href":"",
       "courseid":"Redeem Offer",
       "courseid-href":"https://www.valid.comxyz"
    },
    {
       "order":"1588668201-57",      
       "pagenation":"",
       "pagenation-href":"",
       "courseid":"[Free] ClickHouse crash course. Conquer big data with ease",
       "courseid-href":"https://remove.com/xyz"
    },
    {
       "order":"1588668201-58",      
       "pagenation":"",
       "pagenation-href":"",
       "courseid":"Redeem Offer",
       "courseid-href":"https://www.valid.com/xyz"
    }
 ];

 const filtered = test.filter(d => d['courseid-href'].startsWith("https://remove.com/"));
console.log(filtered);
```

but gets the same JSON without removing

please help me to achieve it

Comment: Use the `filter()` method.

Comment: I don't see `www.invalid.comxyz`, do you mean `remove.com`?

Comment: Use the `.startsWith()` method to test if one string starts with another. That can be used within the filter function.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for letting me know the rules i have update my findings in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicate function for the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function for Arrays is for selecting which items to *keep*, not which items to *remove*. Therefore, you'll want to replace:

```
const filtered = test.filter(d => d['courseid-href'].startsWith("https://remove.com/"));
```

...with something using a `!`:

```
const filtered = test.filter(d => !d['courseid-href'].startsWith("https://remove.com/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
const filtered = data.filter(d => d["courseid-href"] != "https://www.invalid.comxyz")
```

Where `data` is the array of objects will go through and remove any instances where the `courseid-href` property is what you're seeking to remove.

Comment: You'd need to do `d['courseid-href']` since `-` is invalid in dot property notation.

Comment: @Jacob thanks for the answer now am getting revised output but its searching for exact keyword how to remove the object which starts with www.remove.com

Comment: @Jacob thanks for the correction, not sure why I didn't catch that. Edited my answer

Answer (score -1):

you can filter your json array by value

Example:

```
myJson = myJson.filter(function(jsonObject) {
    return jsonObject.courseid-href = "https://www.valid.com/xyz";
});
```

Referencing from this SO entry:
[json remove element by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394653/json-remove-element-by-value)

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, not comparitor.